# How to pass values from the javascript to <Apex:outputlabel>

Tags: apex, javascript

Im constructing a visual force page in which im trying to display a message in `<apex:outputLabel>`
thru javascript . How can i pass the value to the output label from javascript ,

Comment: Are you also using a control class?

Comment: nope! no controller class

Comment: what outputs would you like ? can you give a small example by chance

Comment: Just a text, based on the values in the url i got

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
//the outputlabel is rendered as a label element in html, you should fetch the id by inspecting the source of the page.
var myOutputLabel = document.getElementById('j_id0:outputText');
myOutputLabel.innerHTML='jhsdfsdfjksdnkf';

<apex:outputLabel id="outputText"></apex:outputLabel>
```

Comment: perfect ! man u r awesome

Comment: And one question : won't the ID of the element get changed at anytime

Comment: it will depend on structure of your VF page. If you happen to alter (add / remove) any of the parent of this outputLabel element then yes the id gets changed, else it will remain the same.

Comment: thnx for the info

Comment: For that reason, I prefer to give apex elements a `styleClass`, then select using that class. The class name won't change, regardless of your page structure. Of course, it's more difficult to select an element by class name without a JS library like jQuery, but there are ways to do it, and it's much more stable (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript)

Comment: or you could take it a step further and just use a `label`  instead of an `apex:outputLabel`.  Then the VF parser wont hijack your ids.